# texelFetch weird behavior

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-atlas

I am writing an isometric game engine on OpenGL (version 3.3 specifically). For each wall tileset i have volume mask tileset for the wall relative volume coordinates.

Volume mask looks like this:

[image]

Now i am trying to write a simple lighting system (it kinda looks like that old game, Nox):

[image]

The idea is simple - i generate one-dimensional z-buffer for each light source (in the example i use only one test light spot), in the fragment shader for each fragment i'm figuring out is it lit or not etc.

Here's the vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 scenePosition;
attribute vec3 screenPosition;
attribute vec2 screenTexCoord;
attribute vec2 volTexCoord;
attribute vec2 normalMaskTexCoord;
const int MAX_LIGHTS = 12;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 scrollingMatrixScreen;
out vec2 texCoordFrag;
out vec2 volTexCoordFrag;
out vec2 normalMaskTexCoordFrag;
out vec3 scenePosFrag;

void main(){
    texCoordFrag = screenTexCoord;
    volTexCoordFrag = volTexCoord;
    normalMaskTexCoordFrag = normalMaskTexCoord;
    scenePosFrag = scenePosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * scrollingMatrixScreen * vec4(screenPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
const float specificLength = 0.177469939;
const float M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
const int LIGHT_Z_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D volumeMask;
uniform sampler2D normalMask;
uniform samplerBuffer testLightZBuffer;
uniform vec3 changingVec;

in vec2 texCoordFrag;
in vec3 scenePosFrag;
in vec3 testColorFrag;
in vec2 volTexCoordFrag;
in vec2 normalMaskTexCoordFrag;
in float wallLengthFrag;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
    vec4 trueColor = texture(tex, texCoordFrag);
    if (trueColor == vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))\
        discard;

    float testLightRadius = 4.0;
    vec2 testLightCenter = vec2(2.0, 2.0);
    float lightBrightness = 0.0;
    float lightHeight = 2.0;

    vec3 volCoords = vec3(texture(volumeMask, volTexCoordFrag));
    vec3 trueSceneCoords = vec3(volCoords.x/specificLength, volCoords.y/specificLength, volCoords.z/specificLength) + scenePosFrag;
    vec3 normalCoords = normalize(vec3(texture(normalMask, normalMaskTexCoordFrag)));
    vec2 lightTangentRel = vec2(trueSceneCoords) - testLightCenter;

    if (length(lightTangentRel) <= testLightRadius)
    {
        float angle = acos(dot(normalize(lightTangentRel), vec2(1.0, 0.0)));
        float currentZBufferPoint = angle / (2*M_PI);
        int currentTexelId = int(round(LIGHT_Z_BUFFER_SIZE * currentZBufferPoint));
        vec4 obstRad = texelFetch(testLightZBuffer, currentTexelId);

        if (length(lightTangentRel) < testLightRadius)
        {
            float lightIntensity = cos((length(lightTangentRel)*M_PI/2)/(testLightRadius));
            lightBrightness = lightIntensity;

    }

    vec4 nightColor = vec4(trueColor.x*0.1, trueColor.y*0.1, trueColor.z*0.2, trueColor.w);
    vec4 lightColor = trueColor;
    if (0.0 <= lightBrightness && lightBrightness <= 1.0)
        fragColor = mix(lightColor, nightColor, 0.0);
}
```

The problem is, texelFetch can't handle *currentZBufferPoint* variable, it just doesn't draw ANYTHING, but *lightBrightness* should be at least 0, therefore it must draw at least black pixels. Looks like shader program crashes somewhere, but it compiles completely fine.

So, after several hours i figured out where is the problem - it is here:

```
vec3 volCoords = vec3(texture(volumeMask, volTexCoordFrag));
```

If i replace *texture(volumeMask, volTexCoordFrag)* with anything else, it works.
Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i just figured it out - i just set uniform samplers variables incorrectly.